# Firebase cloud functions with Handlebar templates and nodemailer throws path not found for templates

Tags: path, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

My directory structure within functions directory is as below:

```
 -node_modules
 -assets
  |_ -email
     |_welcomeEmail.html
  |_ -fn
     |_email
       |_sendEmail.ts
  -index.ts
  -package.json
```

sendEmail.ts is imported into the index.ts file after creating a user.

sendEmail.ts

```
            const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            pool: true,
            auth: {
                user: 'xxx@gmail.com',
                pass: 'fjasgd'
            }
        });
        const filePath = path.join(__dirname,'../../assets/email/welcomeEmail.html'); 
        console.log(__dirname);
        const source = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8').toString();
        const template = handlebars.compile(source);
        const replacements = {
            username: userdata.email,
            email: userdata.email,
            password: userdata.password
        };
        const htmlToSend = template(replacements);
```

it always throws an error that it's unable to find the view:

> Error:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/srv/lib/assets/email/welcomeEmail.html' at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18) at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33) at admin.auth.createUser.then.then (/srv/lib/fn/email/sendEmail.js:40:31)

Comment: Please edit the question to show the **complete** code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Updated the code. I missed while posting

Comment: That code isn't complete.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example